# Keyboard input is not working

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I cannot get any input from the keyboard, I dont't know why. Please correct my code so that it works.

In my programm I create a Window wich extends JFrame, then I create the Panel which extends JPanel, then I add the Panel to my Window. The Panel has the KeyListener implemented and it also has the focus requested.

This is my Main class:

```
package dev.thomaslienbacher.spacefighter;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {

    public static Window window;
    public static Panel panel;
    public static int width = 0;
    public static int height = 0;
    public static final int FPS = 35;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        panel = new Panel(FRAMEWIDTH, FRAMEHEIGHT);

        ArrayList<Image> icons = new ArrayList<Image>();
        icons.add(Utils.getImage("res/icon8.png"));

        gameMechanics = new GameMechanics();
        window = new Window(title, 606, 700, icons);
        window.add(panel);
        width = window.getContentPane().getSize().width;
        height = window.getContentPane().getSize().height;

        Timer gameLoopTimer = new Timer(1000 / FPS, new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panel.repaint();
                panel.actionPerformed(null);
            }}
        );
        gameLoopTimer.start();
    }
}
```

This is my Window class:

```
package dev.thomaslienbacher.spacefighter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends JFrame{

    public Window(String title, int width, int height, ArrayList<Image> icons){
        super(title);

        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.setSize(width, height);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);  
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setIconImages(icons);
        this.setCursor(cross);
    }
}
```

This is my Panel class:

```
package dev.thomaslienbacher.spacefighter;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

    public Panel(int width, int height) {
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        this.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
        this.requestFocusInWindow();
        this.requestFocus();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Released");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: does wrapping your `requestFocus` in an `invokeLater` call work? `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> requestFocus());` Also, I wouldn't request focus in the constructor but rather in the method where it is actually used (in this case at the end of `main`)

Comment: You do not seem to have registered action listener to your panel. Try this.addActionListener(this); in your panel constructor. And similarly the key listener too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, it helped putting the requestFocus() at the ned of the Main class. Thank you so much - 1blustone

Comment: @stonedust, the better solution is to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), since `key bindings` will solve the focus issues.